# .NET MAUI WEB CAM PREVIEW

Tags: .net, maui, webcam, aforge

I am new to .dotnet world. I am trying to stream the web cam on my maui screen (Windows Only) . The problem is default MAUI function to do this job is using MediaPicker CaptureAyncPhoto method which is not working on windows machine and reported as bug on github.

So now i am trying with Aforge Video library to preview web cam on my screen here i dont know how to assign stream to xaml image .

here is my xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestWebCam.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout Spacing="25" VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Image  HorizontalOptions="Center"  HeightRequest="300" x:Name="myImage" />

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

Here us my MyMainPage.xaml.cs

```
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using SkiaSharp;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

namespace TestWebCam;


public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private VideoCaptureDevice videoDevice;

    

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
      

        // Get the list of available video devices
        FilterInfoCollection videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        if (videoDevices.Count == 0)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Error", "No video devices found", "OK");
            return;
        }

        // Select the first video device
        videoDevice = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[0].MonikerString);

      
        videoDevice.NewFrame += videoDevice_NewFrame;
       
        videoDevice.Start();

    }

    private void videoDevice_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
       
        using var bitmap = (System.Drawing.Bitmap) eventArgs.Frame.Clone();

      

        //  myImage.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("calendar.png");
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();

        // Stop capturing frames from the video device
        videoDevice.SignalToStop();
        videoDevice.WaitForStop();
    }


}
```

this problem i am facing is this method **videoDevice_NewFrame** how can i bind the myImage to this stream here.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.imagesource.fromstream?view=net-maui-7.0

Answer (score 0):

The [.NET MAUI Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/) may be able to help. It has a [MediaElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/mediaelement) that is supported on Windows.